# Check server resource usage by user on a CentOS VPS

Tags: centos, vps, monitoring

How can I check which account/user is abusing/using the most resources on my VPS?

Quite often, web hosts suspend an account citing high resource usage. How can I check the same on my VPS? I have root access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what resource you wish to account for.

- **CPU**: Install BSD process accounting (package `acct` on Debian; from memory it's `psacct` on CentOS, but I might be misremembering something there); this'll give you a log of all processes run, with UID, CPU/wall time, peak memory usage, etc, all included.  Process as required.
- **RAM**: For "over time" usage, BSD process accounting will do the trick.  If you're after periodic "point in time" analysis (to catch large, long-running processes which are the most important consumer of memory) I'm not aware of anything off the shelf, but something that walks through `/proc` and scoops up the data out of `/proc/X/maps` isn't rocket science.
- **Network**: This isn't a well-covered area for local users; if you're just after their usage of solicited incoming traffic the logs of your various servers can be used to analyse usage; if you're allowing unfettered inbound/outbound connections (not a good idea in the first place) and want to account for that traffic, something like [netacct](http://sourceforge.net/projects/netacct/) might be the least-worst option for this, although if you've got nefarious users it's not hard to get around.
- **Disk space**: A periodic `du` will do for the simple case; if you really want to stop 'em, set up disk quotas.